# How to call methods of isolate scope directve from controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have example of directive that fires spin loader on button press:  <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ua3j4mlNOBU9Y3qN5821?p=preview)</kbd>

I try to create the same directive with isolate scope. Right now the controller calls `scope.init` and `scope.stop` methods.

Here is example of 2 buttons. So I try to show *private* spinner per button.

The current issues is that `ng-click` stopped to work.

Example 2 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FjRV4M58sTz4El1sWjXC?p=preview)</kbd>

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the directive is going to be a child of the controller's scope.  You want to try to eliminate any coupling between your controller and your directive, wherever possible.  So you don't want to be directly calling methods from the directive inside your controller.  That creates direct coupling, which causes lots of issues (makes it really hard to test accurately, and creates dependencies on your code that you don't want).

However, sometimes you have to communicate *somehow* between your controller and your directive.  There are a number of ways of doing this.  The most "standard" way of doing it, would be to use attributes on your directive.  Something like:

```
<button type="submit" loader show-when="valIsTruthy" left="10" ng-click="loadData()" >Load Data</button>
```

This would allow you to specify some value on your controller's scope that will act as a flag to show or hide your loader when the controller's scope property is either truthy or falsy.

Another, and in my opinion more simplified, solution is to use scope events.  In your controller you can do something like:

```
$scope.$emit('show-loader');
// more code here
$scope.$emit('hide-loader');
```

and in your directive, you can do something like:

```
scope.$on('show-loader', function(){
    // write code to show the loader
});
...
scope.$on('hide-loader', function(){
    // hide loader here
});
```

Either way (or any number of other ways) should work for you.  Hope that helps.

Comment: can you fix my 2nd Plunker demo?  with your  way? thanks